# Fine tune EXTRACT HOUR and DAY

Tags: oracle, extract, days, hour

I have a logic as per below query to extract the number of days from timestamp and present in hours.

```
  CASE WHEN LATEST_TIMESTAMP IS NULL

 THEN 
      EXTRACT (HOUR FROM (SYSDATE - CREATION_TIMESTAMP)) + EXTRACT (DAY FROM (SYSDATE - 
      CREATION_TIMESTAMP)) * 24
 ELSE
     EXTRACT (HOUR FROM (LATEST_TIMESTAMP - CREATION_TIMESTAMP)) + EXTRACT (DAY FROM 
    (LATEST_TIMESTAMP - CREATION_TIMESTAMP)) * 24

 END

AS TIME_IN_HOURS
```

It works inefficiently when deal with multiple records, anyway if can fine tune the query?

Comment: What does "inefficiently" mean in this context?

Comment: the query took long time to process for huge number of records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined solution with NVL and Extract

```
select  EXTRACT (DAY FROM(nvl(latest_timestamp, sysdate) - creation_timestamp)) * 24) as time_in_hours from some_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference of two `DATE` datatype values is a *number of days* between them. Therefore, if you "shorten" your code to use `NVL` (for cases where `latest_timestamp` is `NULL`) and simply multiply that result by `24` (to get number of hours), you'd get

```
select (nvl(latest_timestamp, sysdate) - creation_timestamp)) * 24 as time_in_hours
from some_table
```

That result should probably be rounded (but that's easy).

See if it helps.

Comment: the execution time is perfect, but the result rounded such unreadable as the value "+7054 03:34:39.480000" i 'm getting. Can the query handle both latest_timestamp is NULL and NOT NULL?

Comment: NVL handles it; if LATEST_TIMESTAMP is not null, it'll take its value. Otherwise, it'll take SYSDATE.